# How do you enable ION debugging in Android kernel?

Tags: android, memory-leaks, android-ion

I'm trying to track down lost RAM in the Android kernel, and I see from the post below that the ION drivers keep track of this.

[What is the concept behind “Lost RAM” which appears in Dumpsys meminfo?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21881122/what-is-the-concept-behind-lost-ram-which-appears-in-dumpsys-meminfo)

Can someone tell me how to enable ION driver debugging so I can find my lost RAM?

Answer (score 2):

Benjamin Gaignard's Article on Linaro explains ION debugging as below (https://wiki.linaro.org/BenjaminGaignard/ion):

**ION debug**

ION provided a debugfs interface in /sys/kernel/debug/ion/ directory.
Each heap has it own debugfs entry where clients memory usage is displayed: `/sys/kernel/debug/ion/<<heap name>>`

```
$ cat /sys/kernel/debug/ion/ion-heap-1 
          client              pid             size
        test_ion             2890            16384
```

Each client identify by pid have also a debugfs entry: `/sys/kernel/debug/ion/<<pid>>` where memory usage displayed.

```
$ cat /sys/kernel/debug/ion/2890 
       heap_name:    size_in_bytes
      ion-heap-1:    40960 11
```

Easy enough to wrap a script and periodically monitor the output.